# Symfony 2 Doctrine memory usage

Tags: php, memory, symfony, doctrine

I'm creating a query with an entity repository and it seems to have memory leaks.

In my Entity repository class:

```
echo 'mem 1 : ' . (memory_get_usage()/1024/1024) . "<br />\n";
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->select('a','b','c','...');
echo 'mem 2 : ' . (memory_get_usage()/1024/1024) . "<br />\n";
$r = $query->getQuery()->getResult();
echo 'mem 3 : ' . (memory_get_usage()/1024/1024) . "<br />\n";
$this->clear(true);
$query->getQuery()->free(true);
unset($r);
echo 'mem 4 : ' . (memory_get_usage()/1024/1024) . "<br />\n";
```

Output:

> mem 1 : 5.0805282592773
>   mem 2 : 5.0998611450195
>   mem 3 : 91.49528503418
>   mem 4 : 77.939567565918

Why is the memory not back to the initial size (5 MB) after freeing the memory?

And only pass from 91 to 77.

Comment: What if you also call unset($query)?

Comment: Just added unset($query) next to the other unset :
$this->clear(true);
$query->getQuery()->free(true);
unset($query);
unset($r);

but it's the same : mem 4 : 77.849983215332

Comment: And what are the results?

Comment: the same : mem 4 : 77.849983215332

Comment: I think it has something to do with sqllogger enabled in debug mode http://stackoverflow.com/a/10913115/842075

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctrine caches certain aspects of Entities it has loaded. Use

```
$em->clear();
```

to detach all objects from the current entity manager.

Comment: With this, the memory is down to 66 mb (mem 4).

Comment: The additional memory is the result of the $r variable. unset() does not guarantee immediate garbage collection, so the process will retain that memory until the garbage collector has freed it or the process has terminated. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584960/whats-better-at-freeing-memory-with-php-unset-or-var-null for more detail.